# Contact form not submitting information to Terminal

Tags: node.js, express

Im using express, node, bodyParser to pull information from a contact form and post it to the terminal.  When I run the code and access my demo site through LocalHost:3000, upon submitting, my input items are not showing up in the terminal.

I've tried changing the form attributes action="send" action="/send" action="/"

```
    const express = require('express');
    const path = require('path');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');

    const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

    const app = express();

   // View engine setup
    app.engine('handlebars', exphbs());
     app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

    // Static folder
    app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

    / Body Parser Middleware
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      res.render('contact', { layout: false });
     });

    app.post('/send', (req, res) => {
        console.log(res.body);
    });
    //Form HTML code

    <form action="send" method="POST">
    <input name="name" type="text" id="name" placeholder="NAME: First & Last">
    <input name="email" type="text" id="email" placeholder="EMAIL:">
    <textarea name="text" id="text" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="QUESTION OR INQUIRY:"></textarea>
    <br>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried console logging the req instead of the res for the app.post?

Comment: You might add a console.log('/send') inside the post as well to see if your request if even making it to the endpoint. You are sending it a req, which presumably has your form info in it, although you don't have that code posted that would send that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing console.log(req.body) then this should output a long json object. If this is not happening, then you are not hitting the url.

```
const express = require('express');
    const path = require('path');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');

    const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

    const app = express();

   // View engine setup
    app.engine('handlebars', exphbs());
     app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

    // Static folder
    app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

    // Body Parser Middleware
   app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
   app.use(bodyParser.json());

    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      res.render('contact', { layout: false });
     });

    app.post('/send', (req, res) => {
        console.log(res.body);
    });
```

The problem is in your html code. I have made some changes, Try this.

```
 //Form HTML code    
    <form action="http://localhost:9000/send" method="POST">
    <input name="name" type="text" id="name" placeholder="NAME: First & Last">
    <input name="email" type="text" id="email" placeholder="EMAIL:">
    <textarea name="text" id="text" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="QUESTION OR INQUIRY:"></textarea>
    <br>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: I had this form nested in another "parent" form, which apparently is a no-no.  Now it's working. Thank-you @Jithin